# Where is get external data in Excel Online Office 365

Tags: excel, office365, data-connections

I have an Excel Spreadsheet that gets data from a stored procedure in SQL in Azure. No issues, it works from the local station or the Azure VM. I want to use this sheet in Excel Online of office 365. There are option to Refresh connection, but no where to create a connection. I copied the sheet to Onedrive and gave all the appropriate permission and when trying to open it gave error: "We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features:  PivotTable reports that refresh when filters change or use external data ranges (also called query tables)"
No Pivottables or filters are in the sheet. So I wish to recreate it in Excel online, but I cannot find how to add a connection. Excel on line Offcie 365, how to add a connection?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connection-properties-9d3599a9-e9b3-461d-99b2-c5505ddae6e0

Comment: I do not believe it is possible in the online version.

Comment: Thanks Zak, The link states the option is available for Office 365. Perhaps there are different versions, Professional vs Enterprise vs Developer?. It should be possible, otherwise a user would have to type in 1000 of lines of data to generate a chart for example.